# How can I create a loop that will ask questions stored in an object array and also create buttons with the answers written on them?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am trying to create a quiz game asking multiple Harry Potter trivia questions. The quiz has a start screen which explains the rules.

When the start button is pressed, the quiz commences along with the 75-second timer. When an answer is selected incorrectly, 10 seconds are docked off of the overall time. I have created a basic HTML and js file for the quiz but cannot get the questions to cycle along with the answers in the buttons.

```js
var startScreen = document.querySelector(".startScreen");
var startButton = document.querySelector("#startButton");
var quizScreen = document.querySelector(".quizScreen");
var questionText = document.querySelector("#questionText");
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var hpTitle = document.querySelector("#hpTitle");
var buttons = document.querySelector("#buttons");
var timerEl = document.querySelector("#count");

var answerArrofObjIndex = 0;

var answerArrofObj = [{
    question: "What is the name of Harry Potters owl?",
    answerArr: ["Hedwig", "Trevour", "Crookshanks", "Dobby"],
    correctIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: "What is Ron's last name?",
    answerArr: ["Swanson", "Weasley", "Granger", "Potter"],
    correctIndex: 1
  },
  {
    question: "Who is the main villain in Harry Potter",
    answerArr: ["Dumbledoor", "Trevour", "Voldemort", "Seious Black"],
    correctIndex: 2
  },
  {
    question: "Who is Harry Potters godfather?",
    answerArr: ["Tom Riddle", "Severus Snape", "Lucious Malfoy", "Serious Black"],
    correctIndex: 3
  }
]


//start button

startButton.addEventListener("click", setCounter)

function setCounter() {
  if (event.target.matches("button")) {
    startScreen.setAttribute("style", "display: none !important");
    quizScreen.setAttribute("style", "display: block !important");
  }
  var timeLeft = 75;

  var timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    timerEl.textContent = "time left: " + timeLeft;
    timeLeft--;

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      timerEl.textContent = "time left: 0";
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
      endScreen();
    }

  }, 1000);

  displayQuestions();
}


function displayQuestions() {

  if (answerArrofObjIndex !== 0) {
    document.getElementById("questionText").children[1].remove();

  }

  var currentLayout = answerArrofObj[answerArrofObjIndex];

  var question = document.createElement("h3");
  question.classList.add("text-center");
  question.setAttribute("src", currentLayout.answerArr[currentLayout.correctIndex])

  document.getElementById("questionText").appendChild(question);

  for (var i = 0; i < currentLayout.questionArr.length; i++) {
    setQuestion(i)
  }

}

setCounter();
```

```html
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Harry Potter Quiz</title>
</head>

<body class="text-monospace">

  <header>
    <a href="high-scores.html" class="text-left btn btn-outline-success mt-0 ml-3 float-left" type="button">view
                high
                scores</a>
    <p class="h4 text-right mr-4 mt-2"><span id="count">time left: 75</span></p>
  </header>

  <main class="container text-center">
    <article class="startScreen">

      <h1 class="text-center m-5" id="hpTitle">Harry Potter Quiz!</h1>
      <p class="text-center" id="instructions"> Welcome to the Harry Potter quiz, if you would like to test your knowledge on all things wizard and witch please click the start button. You have 75 seconds to complete the quiz, everytime you answer incorectly you are docked 10 seconds, the time
        left after the quiz is your final score.
      </p>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-4" id="startButton"> start the quiz!</button>
    </article>

    <div class="d-none quizScreen">

      <div id="questionText">
        <h3>question goes here</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="buttons">
        <button id="0" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4">answer1</button>
        <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">answer2</button>
        <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">answwe3</button>
        <button id="3" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">answer4</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="endScreen d-none">

      <h3 id="endTitle"></h3>
      <p id="finalScore">your final score is:</p>
    </div>
  </main>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

High scores:

```js
var startScreen = document.querySelector(".startScreen");
var startButton = document.querySelector("#startButton");
var quizScreen = document.querySelector(".quizScreen");
var questionText = document.querySelector("#questionText");
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var hpTitle = document.querySelector("#hpTitle");
var buttons = document.querySelector("#buttons");
var timerEl = document.querySelector("#count");

var answerArrofObjIndex = 0;

var answerArrofObj = [{
    question: "What is the name of Harry Potters owl?",
    answerArr: ["Hedwig", "Trevour", "Crookshanks", "Dobby"],
    correctIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: "What is Ron's last name?",
    answerArr: ["Swanson", "Weasley", "Granger", "Potter"],
    correctIndex: 1
  },
  {
    question: "Who is the main villain in Harry Potter",
    answerArr: ["Dumbledoor", "Trevour", "Voldemort", "Seious Black"],
    correctIndex: 2
  },
  {
    question: "Who is Harry Potters godfather?",
    answerArr: ["Tom Riddle", "Severus Snape", "Lucious Malfoy", "Serious Black"],
    correctIndex: 3
  }
]


//start button

startButton.addEventListener("click", setCounter)

function setCounter() {
  if (event.target.matches("button")) {
    startScreen.setAttribute("style", "display: none !important");
    quizScreen.setAttribute("style", "display: block !important");
  }
  var timeLeft = 75;

  var timeInterval = setInterval(function() {
    timerEl.textContent = "time left: " + timeLeft;
    timeLeft--;

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      timerEl.textContent = "time left: 0";
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
      endScreen();
    }

  }, 1000);

  displayQuestions();
}


function displayQuestions() {

  if (answerArrofObjIndex !== 0) {
    document.getElementById("questionText").children[1].remove();

  }

  var currentLayout = answerArrofObj[answerArrofObjIndex];

  var question = document.createElement("h3");
  question.classList.add("text-center");
  question.setAttribute("src", currentLayout.answerArr[currentLayout.correctIndex])

  document.getElementById("questionText").appendChild(question);

  for (var i = 0; i < currentLayout.questionArr.length; i++) {
    setQuestion(i)
  }

}

setCounter();
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>High scores!</title>
</head>

<body class="text-monospace">

  <a href="index.html" class="text-left btn btn-outline-success m-3 float-left" type="button">back to quiz</a>
  <div class="container">

    <h1>High Scores!</h1>

  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like you could loop through the object.answerArr of a question starting with 0 and set the answer buttons text with their values. It will require having the question index available, but that seems to already be done with `answerArrofObjIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

I sense your problem is how to loop through you array of object.

```
answerArrofObj.forEach((el) => {
    let quest = el.question //the question
    let ansArr = el.answerArr  //array of answers

    //You can perform your logicS here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough the questions array, build a question
Then loop trough the answer array and build the answers

This can be done easiest with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Example

```js
var answerArrofObj = [{
    question: "What is the name of Harry Potters owl?",
    answerArr: ["Hedwig", "Trevour", "Crookshanks", "Dobby"],
    correctIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: "What is Ron's last name?",
    answerArr: ["Swanson", "Weasley", "Granger", "Potter"],
    correctIndex: 1
  },
  {
    question: "Who is the main villain in Harry Potter",
    answerArr: ["Dumbledoor", "Trevour", "Voldemort", "Seious Black"],
    correctIndex: 2
  },
  {
    question: "Who is Harry Potters godfather?",
    answerArr: ["Tom Riddle", "Severus Snape", "Lucious Malfoy", "Serious Black"],
    correctIndex: 3
  }
]

let HTML = "";
for (const i in answerArrofObj) {
  HTML += `<h2>${answerArrofObj[i].question}</h2>`;
  for (const j in answerArrofObj[i].answerArr) {
    HTML += `<input type="radio" value="${j}" name="question${i}" id="${i}${j}"></input>`;
    HTML += `<label for="${i}${j}">${answerArrofObj[i].answerArr[j]}</label>`;
  }
}
document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = HTML;
```

```html
<div id="holder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we will define a global context, there must be at least three variables in it, 'timeLeft', 'answerArrofObjIndex' and 'timeInterval' (must be declared outside the scope of any function).

```js
var timeLeft = 75;
var answerArrofObjIndex = 0;
var timeInterval = null;
```

Now we need a function to draw the current question on the screen.

```js
/*
q: question in the answerArrofObj array
onAnswered: callback called when any of the options is clicked, receives as a parameter a boolean indicating whether the answer is correct
*/
function drawQuestion(q, onAnswered) {
  questionText.querySelector("h3").innerText = q.question;
  q.answerArr.forEach((option, i) => {
    try {
      var old_button = buttons.querySelector(
        "button:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")"
      );
      var new_element = old_button.cloneNode(true);
      new_element.innerHTML = option;
      new_element.addEventListener("click", () => onAnswered(q.correctIndex === i));
      old_button.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_button);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error while draw the ' + (i + 1) +  "th button:", error);
    }
  });
}
```

There is also an error in the div selector where the buttons are, a class has been assigned but the selector is looking for an id

```js
var buttons = document.querySelector(".buttons");
```

with these changes made, only the treatment at the end of execution was missing (the `endScreen` function)

A version can be found here:

```js
var startScreen = document.querySelector(".startScreen");
var startButton = document.querySelector("#startButton");
var quizScreen = document.querySelector(".quizScreen");
var questionText = document.querySelector("#questionText");
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var hpTitle = document.querySelector("#hpTitle");
var buttons = document.querySelector(".buttons");
var timerEl = document.querySelector("#count");

var answerArrofObj = [
  {
    question: "What is the name of Harry Potters owl?",
    answerArr: ["Hedwig", "Trevour", "Crookshanks", "Dobby"],
    correctIndex: 0
  },
  {
    question: "What is Ron's last name?",
    answerArr: ["Swanson", "Weasley", "Granger", "Potter"],
    correctIndex: 1
  },
  {
    question: "Who is the main villain in Harry Potter",
    answerArr: ["Dumbledoor", "Trevour", "Voldemort", "Seious Black"],
    correctIndex: 2
  },
  {
    question: "Who is Harry Potters godfather?",
    answerArr: [
      "Tom Riddle",
      "Severus Snape",
      "Lucious Malfoy",
      "Serious Black"
    ],
    correctIndex: 3
  }
];

//start button

startButton.addEventListener("click", setCounter);

var timeLeft = 75;
var answerArrofObjIndex = 0;
var timeInterval = null;

function setCounter() {
  timeLeft = 75;
  if (event.target.matches("button")) {
    startScreen.setAttribute("style", "display: none !important");
    quizScreen.setAttribute("style", "display: block !important");
  }

  var timeInterval = setInterval(function () {
    timeLeft--;
    timerEl.textContent = "time left: " + timeLeft;

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
      endScreen();
    }
  }, 1000);

  displayQuestions();
}

function displayQuestions() {
  if (answerArrofObjIndex >= answerArrofObj.length) {
    if (timeInterval) {
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
    }
    endScreen();
    return;
  }
  var currentLayout = answerArrofObj[answerArrofObjIndex];
  drawQuestion(currentLayout, (rightAnswer) => {
    if (!rightAnswer) {
      timeLeft -= 10;
      timerEl.textContent = "time left: " + timeLeft;
    }
    answerArrofObjIndex++;
    displayQuestions();
  });
}

function drawQuestion(q, onAnswered) {
  questionText.querySelector("h3").innerText = q.question;
  q.answerArr.forEach((option, i) => {
    try {
      var old_button = buttons.querySelector(
        "button:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")"
      );
      var new_element = old_button.cloneNode(true);
      new_element.innerHTML = option;
      new_element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        onAnswered(q.correctIndex === i);
      });
      old_button.parentNode.replaceChild(new_element, old_button);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while draw the " + (i + 1) + "th button:", error);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-VCmXjywReHh4PwowAiWNagnWcLhlEJLA5buUprzK8rxFgeH0kww/aWY76TfkUoSX"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Harry Potter Quiz</title>
  </head>

  <body class="text-monospace">
    <header>
      <a
        href="high-scores.html"
        class="text-left btn btn-outline-success mt-0 ml-3 float-left"
        type="button"
        >view high scores</a
      >
      <p class="h4 text-right mr-4 mt-2">
        <span id="count">time left: 75</span>
      </p>
    </header>

    <main class="container text-center">
      <article class="startScreen">
        <h1 class="text-center m-5" id="hpTitle">Harry Potter Quiz!</h1>
        <p class="text-center" id="instructions">
          Welcome to the Harry Potter quiz, if you would like to test your
          knowledge on all things wizard and witch please click the start
          button. You have 75 seconds to complete the quiz, everytime you answer
          incorectly you are docked 10 seconds, the time left after the quiz is
          your final score.
        </p>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mt-4" id="startButton">
          start the quiz!
        </button>
      </article>

      <div class="d-none quizScreen">
        <div id="questionText"><h3>question goes here</h3></div>

        <div class="buttons">
          <button id="0" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4">
            answer1
          </button>
          <button id="1" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
            answer2
          </button>
          <button id="2" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
            answwe3
          </button>
          <button id="3" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
            answer4
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="endScreen d-none">
        <h3 id="endTitle"></h3>
        <p id="finalScore">your final score is:</p>
      </div>
    </main>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-XEerZL0cuoUbHE4nZReLT7nx9gQrQreJekYhJD9WNWhH8nEW+0c5qq7aIo2Wl30J"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```